# Embedding youtube in .net web browser not working

Tags: .net, youtube, embed

I know that there are many examples and answered questions regarding this subject, but trying all of them without success.

I tried for example :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/embed/rsg3xCtAsYQ")...> black screen

WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/v/rsg3xCtAsYQ").......> black screen
```

Trying both url's in internet explorer directly will show the video normally!

This is a serious problem when trying to write an application needs to show youtube file inside a winform.

Please can anyone help me? What's wrong here?